# Redirect subdomain to a domain using CNAME A NS AAAA TXT MX record

Tags: redirect, dns

I am wondering if there is any way to redirect a subdomain to a domain in a fashion that it works like a parking site.

Let's say I have www.example.com and have a URL www.example.com/article.html. Now I want to set blog.example.com using only CNAME, A, NS, AAAA, TXT or MX record so that if anyone hit blog.example.com/article.html to be redirected to www.example.com/article.html.

I don't want to enter one record for each URL, I want this to wrok for all htmls under example.com. Also, I don't have access to use .htaccess on the hsoting server, I only have access to DNS setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DNS alone, you will not be able to specify directories or files for redirection. Records are only for domains without specific directories or filenames (the part after the hostname).

If you want to redirect a subdomain to another with the directory or filename specified (i.e. not a domain-level redirect such as blog.x.tld to www.x.tld but blog.x.tld/file.html to www.x.tld/file.html for example), the best solution is to use a rewrite on the server level. With Apache web server, mod_rewrite allows you to redirect a particular URL to another, with the granularity you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wildcard CNAME record:

```
*.example.com. IN CNAME www.example.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

Configure domain redirects and URL forwarding with a simple DNS record

http://redirect.name/